# Студия для PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Сейчас переводим код с oracle на PostgreSQL. Просьба посоветовать хорошую студию. Мы пользуемся pgAdmin, первое впечатление ужасное, самый главный косяк что может скомпилить функцию с ошибками, а потом отлаживать приходиться вызывая приложение. Желательно что-нибудь бесплатное или очень хорошее платное.

Answer (score 1):

может [datagrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) она платная, но есть a free 30-day trial чтобы попробовать. Лично пользую для pgsql, mysql и sqlite.